# EJS Tags in external css

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to refactor a nodeJs project and my css is in my .ejs file. I need to put some dynamic data in my css file. I need to have dynamic data in my css, when my css is in my EJS file it's good.

But when I put my css into an external file, nothing happens!

So, how can I inject ejs tag in my external stylesheet file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the questions to which one has to ask you - why do you want to do that? You are asking about a solution to a problem that you didn't describe.

By suspicion is that you are trying to use a templating system for something that could be done with a CSS preprocessor like Sass or Less. Particularly Less can be easily used on both the client side and server side. See http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

Now, if you really want to use a templating system created for HTML to generate CSS then you will have to take few things into account: You need to store your CSS templates somewhere where your HTML templates are stored, not where you store your static assets like images. Then, your server will have to serve your generated CSS with a correct MIME type. Then, your HTML will have to reference the styles using a URL to your generated CSS that will be generated on every request instead of being served directly from disk.